¿Cómo Identificar y reemplazar caracteres repetidos en Oracle?
Oracle, tengo un campo de correo electrónico donde el punto se llega a repetir en más de una ocasión; necesito identificarlos y reemplazarlos por un solo punto.
Ejemplos

Correo..@hotmail.com
Correo....@hormail.com
Prueba.correo..........@correo.mx

El punto repetido es consecutivo y lo único que sé es que se repite más de 2 veces, sin longitud fija.
¿Cómo podría reemplazarlos por un solo punto?

Con una expresión regular: SELECT regexp_replace( 'uno...dos@hotmail.com', '\.{2,}', '.' ) FROM dual.

"lo único que sé es que se repite más de 2 veces" - Si es así, ¿por qué hay un ejemplo con dos puntos (Correo..@hotmail.com)? ¿Existen direcciones con dos puntos, también? En este caso, ¿quieres convertirlas o no? Y Sal tiene razón, la solución más simple es con regexp_replace.

@Sal, debieras publicar una respuesta, pues en realidad es mucho mejor que la que ya está y que escribí yo. Ref

Para identificar las filas que tienen dos puntos seguidos, puedes valerte del operador like, por ejemplo:
select *
  from MiTabla 
 where correo_electronico like '%..%';

Encontrará todos los registros donde haya dos puntos seguidos en cualquier parte de la cadena almacenada en el campo correo_electronico.
Para reemplazar, puedes valerte de la función replace().
El tema aquí es que, dado que se puede repetir una cantidad indefinida de veces. Una manera sencilla de asegurarte que no quede ninguno sería con un ciclo, por ejemplo:
declare  
    contador integer;
begin
    select count(1)
      into contador
      from prueba
     where email like '%..%';
    while (contador <> 0)
    loop
        update prueba 
          set email = replace(email, '..', '.')
        where email like '%..%';
        select count(1)
          into contador
          from prueba
         where email like '%..%';
    end loop;
end;

Puedes probar el ejercicio que dejé en Oracle Live

Muchas gracias, me parece excelente la opción. Buscaba algo que pudiera ser dentro de la sentencia Select, sin embargo, no hay forma más que recorrer la cadena (por lo que veo). Te agradezco tú valioso tiempo y rápida atención. ☺️. Me sirve mucho el código.

Me alegra que te sirviera. En la pregunta no mencionaste que lo querías en un select.

No need to write a PL/SQL function for this. Just use regexp_replace, which has been available for such tasks for about twenty years now.

@Thorsten, es un gran consejo, debieras escribir una respuesta con el código. Yo suelo no tirar tanto de expresiones regulares, pero justo este es el tipo de tarea en el que vienen como anillo al dedo.

El usuario Sal ya propuso la solución ayer en los comentarios de la cuestión. :-)

oh, cierto, no había visto su comentario, que llegó después que yo escribí esta respuesta. Ya le comenté, pues creo que debiera publicarla como tal. Un saludo.
